# Cones, Differentials, and Volume Error Estimates

Tags: calculus, volume, error-function

A cone with a circular base has a height of 40 cm and its radius at the base is 15 cm. Each measurement has 0.3 cm precision. With the help of differentials, estimate the greatest error that is incurred on the volume of the cone.

I first started by determining what the function for the volume of a cone was. This was $πr^2⋅\frac{h}{3}$.

Now, for finding our differentials, we have that $f_r(r,h)=π2r\frac{h}{3}$ and for $f_h(r,h)=πr^2⋅\frac{1}{3}$.

Now, for our linerization function, we have $L(r,h)=f(a,b)+f_r(a,b)(r-a)+f_h(a,b)(h-a)$ which, having inputed all the variables gives us $L(r,h)=π225 \frac{40}{3} + π30 \frac{40}{3}(r-15) + \pi 225\cdot\frac{1}{3}(h-40)$.

My thought process was that, in finding the linearization for the function of the volume of the cone I could then simply find the difference between $L(15.3,40.3)$ and $L(15,40)$ which would give me some "error" volume.

Why/where is my this logic incorrect?

**edit**: See comments below. Note that reasoning is sound, but errors in differentiation as well as in the understanding of "linearization" ($x^2$ is not linear) led to incorrect answer.

Comment: I notice your $f_r(r,h)$ expression contains an extra factor of $1/3$, but shouldn't it just be $\pi2r \cdot \frac{h}{3}$? And $f_h(r,h)$ has a factor of $1/h$, but shouldn't that be omitted because $f$ is linear in $h$? i.e. shouldn't it be $f_h(r,h) = \pi r^2 \cdot \frac{1}{3}$?

Comment: You're right. I've since removed it and corrected other typos.

Comment: But what about the $1/h$ factor in $f_h$? You also use it in your expression for $L(r,h)$, and it seems erroneous to me. If so, that could explain why your approximation is off.

Comment: Yes, you're correct on the second count. Let me correct this in my calculations and see what the results yield. Everything else seems in order?

Comment: I think the rest is correct, except that $r$ appears twice in your new expression for $L(r,h)$. I believe the $r$ in the final term is supposed to be the "central" $r$, that is $15$. The other $r$ in the second term is a variable (and you will be setting it to $15.3$).

Comment: You're saying that I should have $L(r,h)=\pi 225 \frac{40}{3}+\pi 30 \frac{40}{3}(r-15)+\pi \color{blue}{15}^2\cdot \frac{1}{3}(h-40)$ and that it is in this equation that my estimate of 15.3 for $r$ and 40.3 for $h$ should go?

edit: This is correct. Thank you much WB-man.

Comment: Exactly. Anyway, there really can't be an $r^2$ term in $L(r,h)$. If there was, it wouldn't be *linear*!